# Can program return/terminate before the kill function is called?

Tags: c++, c, signals, kill

I am a little confused about how the kill(pid, signal) function works - I believe it is asynchronous, so the signal may not arrive until after a few more instructions have been executed. My question is, if you call kill(pid, signal) and then return in the next line (As seen below), are you guaranteed that the signal will be caught and handled before the program terminates, or is it possible to exit without handling the signal if we run "return 0" before the kill function finishes?

```
kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
return 0;
```

Comment: Are you implying that `pid` here is the pid of the process itself? Or some child process?

Comment: The man page says "On success (at least one signal was sent), zero is returned." The send is guaranteed, but receive and action on that signal by receiving part is not guaranteed (very likely not) before return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a process sends a signal only to itself, and that signal is not blocked, and there are no other pending signals for that process, then the signal will be sent synchronously (that is,  before `kill()` returns).

That's not enough of a guarantee to be 100% reliable, so you might prefer not to rely on it. Another process might happen to send a different signal at precisely the same time, for example; that is probably outside of your control.

If a process sends a signal to a different process, then there is no guarantee that it will be received before `kill()` returns. But it will be sent even if the signalling function terminates.

If more than one process will receive the signal, `kill` may return after the first signal is sent, which is not guaranteed to be the signalling process. Again, this might result in the process returning before the signal is received. Some platforms may offer additional guarantees.

Here's the [Posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html):

> If the value of `pid` causes `sig` to be generated for the sending process, and if `sig` is not blocked for the calling thread and if no other thread has `sig` unblocked or is waiting in a `sigwait()` function for `sig`, either `sig` or at least one pending unblocked signal shall be delivered to the sending thread before `kill()` returns.